Is TQBF in CNF is still PSPACE-complete
TQBF(Totally Quantified Boolean Formula) is a PSPACE-complete question. I wonder that if it restricted to CNF is still PSPACE-complete. TQBF-CNF means that the part following the quantifier is a CNF.
I tried to prove that TQBF can be reduced to TQBF-CNF but failed as it need an exponential time to change a formula into CNF.
I would much appreciate an answer or an idea

Yes, it is still PSPACE-complete.  Let $Q_1 x_i \cdots Q_k x_k . \varphi(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ be a TQBF problem, where each $Q_i$ is a quantifier.  Apply the Tseytin transform to $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ to get an equisatisfiable CNF formula $\Psi(x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1})$, so that $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_k) \Leftrightarrow \exists x_{k+1} . \Psi(x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1})$.  Then the original TQBF problem is equivalent to
$$Q_1 x_1 \cdots Q_k x_k \exists x_{k+1} .\Psi(x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1}),$$
which is an instance of TQBF-CNF.  Therefore, any algorithm to solve TQBF-CNF can be used to solve TQBF.
As explained in Wikipedia, the size of $\Psi$ is polynomial in the size of $\varphi$.  Note that $x_{k+1}$ might represent multiple variables.  The number of added variables is also polynomial in the size of $\varphi$.
See also Is there a known way to convert any $QBF_2$-formula into an equisatisfiable $QBF_2$-formula in CNF in polynomial time?.

Thanks for the answer! But I'm confused abut of the number of variables in $\Psi$, why do we need to add exactly one variable? In wikipedia, the example has the same number of variables after Tseytin transform.

@ywang22THU, see revised answer.  It certainly doesn't have the same number of variables: the Tseytin transform adds more variables.  If you're not clear how the Tseytin transform works, I suggest spending some time studying up on it -- search for other expositions of it, try working through a few simple examples with pencil and paper, etc. -- and if you're still stuck, ask a new question about whatever specific aspect you can't figure out.

Got it! I tried some examples just know. The number of extra variables is equivalent with the subformulas expect literals. Thanks!
